# Python - Replace all instances of string EXCEPT for those in regex

Tags: python, regex

I would like to replace all mentions of the string "camel" except when it occurs in the context of the below in bold:

```
Source{[Name="Camel"]}
```

In that case I would like to leave it as is.  I have a regex which can identify this format:

```
Source{\[Name=\"(\w+)\"\]}
```

So for example:

```
let
    Source=#"Middle East",
    Camel = Source{[Name="Camel"]}[Content],
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(Camel)
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Invoke Custom 
    Function1", {"Camel"})
```

should be changed to:

```
let
        Source=#"Middle East",
        Dog = Source{[Name="Camel"]}[Content],
        #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(Dog)
        #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Invoke Custom 
        Function1", {"Dog"})
```

Comment: none of this looks valid python code to me

Comment: I think it's an example input, not the code itself

Answer (score 0):

steps:

1. Replace all occurrences of `camel` to `dog`
2. Replace all occurrences of `source{[name="dog"]}` to `source{[name="camel"]}`

inefficient but will do the trick

Comment: What if there was `source{[name="dog"]}` there before?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(Source{\[Name="\w+"]})|\bCamel\b', lambda x: x.group(1) or 'Dog', text)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RdpYTW)

**Details**

- `(Source{\[Name="\w+"]})|\bCamel\b` - matches and captures into Group 1 the pattern you have (`Source{[Name="some_word123"}}` like string) or will match a `Camel` whole word
- `lambda x: x.group(1) or 'Dog'` callable will put back the text in Group 1 if Group 1 matched, else, the word `Camel` will be replaced with `Dog`.

Answer (score 0):

The key insight here is that no part of the string can match twice. So if `Source{[Name="Camel"]}` matches, `Camel` inside it can't match. So we make regexp an alternation, and check if we matched the part that we wanted to replace, otherwise we just return what we found, unchanged:

```
import re
camel_re = re.compile(r"Source\{\[Name=\"Camel\"\]\}|(?P<replacee>Camel)")

def camel_replacer(m):
    if m.group('replacee'):
        return "Dog"
    else:
        return m.group()

camel_re.sub(camel_replacer, text)
```